# External Library errors with CIMG

Tags: cimg

I'm having this one external symbols error compiling cimg code. Its basic code to test the library

I'm using Visual Studio Command Prompt with this command:

```
cl test.cpp /link user32.lib gdi32.lib
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol   
__imp__SHGetSpecialFolderPathA@16 referenced in function "char const * __cdecl  cimg_library::cimg::programfiles_path(char const * const,bool)" (?   programfiles_path@cimg@cimg_library@@YAPBDQBD_N@Z)
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Please show your code! I guess you tried to open a file and gave a special synonym for your Desktop or login directory as the filename.

Comment: umm I dont understand how to paste code in here hehe it only makes #include look like code :/

Comment: Paste it. Select with mouse. Then click `{}` in the  Formatting Bar beside **Bold** and *Italic*.

Comment: you're missing Shell32.lib